# Python - issue with extracting metadata from the image

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to extract metadata from the image with code I put together below:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
import pandas as pd
import glob
import urllib
import itertools

def get_exif(fn):
    ret = {}
    i = Image.open(fn)
    info = i._getexif()
    for tag, value in info.items():
        decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
        ret[decoded] = value
    return ret

LoadingDir = "C:/IMAGES/TEST/"
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in glob.glob(LoadingDir+'*.jpg'):
    data = get_exif(file)
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([data])
    temp_df = temp_df.loc[:,['ExifImageWidth','ExifImageHeight', 'XResolution', 'YResolution']]
    final_df = final_df.append(temp_df)
final_df
```

When i run the code on single image without for function, it works however when i run it as is here, i get this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-48-a739cd753170> in <module>
     18 final_df = pd.DataFrame()
     19 for file in glob.glob(LoadingDir+'*.jpg'):
---> 20     data = get_exif(file)
     21     temp_df = pd.DataFrame([data])
     22     temp_df = temp_df.loc[:,['ExifImageWidth','ExifImageHeight', 'XResolution', 'YResolution']]

<ipython-input-48-a739cd753170> in get_exif(fn)
     10     i = Image.open(fn)
     11     info = i._getexif()
---> 12     for tag, value in info.items():
     13         decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
     14         ret[decoded] = value

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `info = i._getexif()` returned `None`

Comment: EXIF data in a JPEG file is entirely optional.  You have apparently encountered a file with no such metadata included.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to what Jason said.  You just have found an image without the metadata.  In your function, you can assign "None" to each of the attributes you're looking for - that seems like a good option to keep your data output referencable.

Comment: Thank you for this input. How do i assign None to each attributes?

Comment: If you wrote the operation that is generating the attributes, just set it to None there. 
 If not, use setattr(info, 'items', None) should work if the properties aren't locked.